# how to get records from an specific ID calculated from date?

Tags: entity-framework

I have many records that has a datetime field:

- MyTable(ID, StartDate,...)

And I have as parameter a `startDate`, I would like to get all the records that have a `startDate` >= than the date set in the parameter and also I would like the record which ID is ID -1 of the ID of the first record which `startDate` >= of the date of the parameter (first record when the result is ordered by date).

Something like that:

```
dbContext.MyTable.Where(x => x.ID >= dbContext.MyTable.OrderBy(y => y.StartDate).Where(y => y.StartDate >= myDate).First()).ToList();
```

But I get an error because I can't use `First()` in this place.

Also if I would use it, first execute the query to the database, but I don't want to do it at this point, because I am constructing a dynamic query and I only want one trip to the database.

So I would like to know if it is possible to use as condition the first element of a result.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Take(1)` as replacement of `First`.

```
dbContext.MyTable
    .Where(x => 
        dbContext.MyTable
       .OrderBy(y => y.StartDate)
       .Where(y => y.StartDate >= myDate)
       .Take(1)
       .Any(y => x.ID >= y.ID))
    .ToList();
```